# Python returns a complex number when negative number is powered with fractional, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I know the methods to get the actual cube root of a negative number in python, however, my question is when simply writing.

```
(-1000)**(1/3)
```

The output will be

```
5+8.660254037844384j
```

I am confused why does python return a complex number instead of simply returning -10 as output. Because mathematically -10 is the correct answer for cube root of -1000.

What is the reason behind this specific behavior of python? Let me know if I am wrong mathematically.

Comment: "Because mathematically -10 is the correct answer for cube root of -1000." No. A cube root of a real number has three solutions: one solution is real, and two are complex. -10 is _a_ correct answer; not _the_ correct answer. Check this: `(5+8.660254037844384j)**3` (not quite -1000, but that's within error margin).

Comment: thank you very much @Amadan for explanation, however I am still confused why python chose this specific complex number as an answer and not a real number.

Comment: It does not test which one is real, it just takes the first one it finds. This is the same as `25**0.5` why whould he choose 5 instead of -5?

Comment: ohkay thanks for the help @BlueSheepToken